# Label is possible part text for left and part text to right?

Tags: c#, winforms, label

Label is possible part text for left and part text to right?

```
        int x = 5;
        label1.Text = "MY TEXT FROM LEFT : " + x.ToString();
```

Where, x from right?
This Visual Studio 2013 and Windows Forms Application

My new idea:

```
 string length = "";

 for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) 
   length += " ";

 label1.Text = "MY TEXT FROM LEFT : " + length +  x.ToString();
```

But, length of my *window* = ???

Comment: What is the question, please?

Comment: No, you can't format runs of text with different alignments in a single label. you'll need two separate labels and a containing element for that.

Comment: How to make some of the text to the left and right to one part of the text (the length of the window)

Comment: are u using a xaml form or a winform?

Comment: please , look edit question. How to count lenght my window?

Comment: my windows lenght = lenght; for (i = 0; i < lenght; i++) separate = " "; :)) good idea?

Comment: Dennis Larisch - no.

Comment: FYI, to make a string 50 spaces long, you don't need a loop, just: `string length = new string(' ', 50);`

Comment: You can do your loop code and on each loop measure the result. For this use Graphics.MeasureString (or TextRednderer.MeasureText) until it overflows the size you want..

Comment: this is not good idea. . .

Comment: How to calculate the length of this fragment? http://imgur.com/a/WIAjv

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, perhaps something like this is what you're trying to achieve?

```
var leftString = "Left string:";
var rightString = "Right string";

var graphics = textBox1.CreateGraphics();
var leftStringWidth = (int) graphics.MeasureString(leftString, textBox1.Font).Width;
var rightStringWidth = (int) graphics.MeasureString(rightString, textBox1.Font).Width;
var spaceWidth = (int) graphics.MeasureString(" ", textBox1.Font).Width;               
var padding = new string(' ', 
    (textBox1.Width - leftStringWidth - rightStringWidth) / spaceWidth);

textBox1.Text = leftString + padding + rightString;
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Yes, effects OK. But not work max windows .. or different media screen sizing

Answer (score 1):

You could subscribe to the paint event to draw the underline and second string:

```
private void label1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var rightString = "Right string";

    var rightStringWidth = e.Graphics.MeasureString(rightString, label1.Font).Width;

    var rightStringXLocation = label1.Width - rightStringWidth;

    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(label1.ForeColor))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(rightString, label1.Font, brush, new PointF(rightStringXLocation, 0));

        var lineHeight = label1.Height - 5;
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(brush), e.Graphics.MeasureString(label1.Text, label1.Font).Width, lineHeight, rightStringXLocation, lineHeight);
    }
}
```

To resize automatically with the window you will also need to set Anchor to Left, Right:

```
this.label1.Anchor = (AnchorStyles)(AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right);
```

Comment: Form1.Designer.cs

Comment: Error 1 The name 'AnchorStyles' does not exist in the current context

Comment: this.label1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;

Answer (score 0):

Configure your label as follows:

- Anchor: **Top, Left, Right**
- Autosize: **False**
- TextAlign: **TopRight**

And widen your label to window width. This way the text will be aligned to the right of the form.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Try the following code to measure width and set appropriate number of underlines. Note that we measure 1000 of underlines to make it more precise. `Button` and `Random` are added for demonstration puproses. The result is not 100% precise, but you can't achieve more with just adding underline characters.

```
private Random _rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

private static float measureTextWidth(string text, Font font, Graphics g)
{
    SizeF size = g.MeasureString(text, font);
    return size.Width;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Graphics g = label1.CreateGraphics())
    {
        string leftText = "Some caption";
        string rightText = new string('V', _rnd.Next(50));

        float leftWidth = measureTextWidth(leftText, label1.Font, g);
        float rightWidth = measureTextWidth(rightText, label1.Font, g);
        float underlineWidth = measureTextWidth(new string('_', 1000), label1.Font, g );
        underlineWidth = underlineWidth / 1000.0f;

        float allSpacesWidth = this.Width - leftWidth - rightWidth;
        int numberOfSpaces = (int)(allSpacesWidth / underlineWidth);

        label1.Text = leftText + new string('_', numberOfSpaces) + rightText;
    }
```

There is advanced method to measure string size if `Graphics.MeasureString` will be not precise enough:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2118/Bypass-Graphics-MeasureString-limitations

Comment: I want to have text and left and right simultaneously. I've already found a way to do this. But I do not know too much, I do not know how to count the length in the program window between the left edge and the right. This is probably a problem how to convert PX to numeric values for int lenght = ... so that I can insert it in for (...) and generate spaces between.

Comment: @J.Doe You can easily simulate the same result using two labels at the same time.

Comment: Between the label should be underlined. I do not know how to do that - two labels.

Comment: @J.Doe Please check updated answer. It should work for all windows width and for any test. But make sure that window has enought space to fit both left and right parts of text, otherwise there might be an error.

Comment: @J.Doe Are you sure you call the label updating logic after resizing the form?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use 2 labels instead of one:

Place TableLayoutPanel (with docking or anchor as you need) on your form.

Panel should have 1 row and 2 columns (AutoSize)

Add 2 labels to panel (one with anchor Left second with anchor Right)
set "left text" to first label and "right text" to second one.